# Couldn't get value from Checkbox using name attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, checkbox

I put checkbox in .cshtml page with name attribute named "bSendEmail" to get the value as a boolean for further process. In post action method, I used a boolean parameter to get whether the checkbox is checked or not but I didn't get the value as true even the checkbox is checked. It always gives false.

I posted below what I am have tried

In .cshtml:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="ItemIndex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 text-center mt-3">
            @if (g_EnableEmail == Constants.GeneralIndicator.Yes)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendMail" name="bSendEmail" class="my-checkbox" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSendMail" name="bSendEmail" class="my-checkbox" disabled />
                <input type="hidden" name="bSendEmail" />
            }
            <label for="chkSendMail" class="head-label2">Send Email Notification</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 text-center mt-10">
            <button type="submit" asp-route-bConfirm="@false" asp-action="ItemIndex" class="genric-btn info circle"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
            <button type="submit" asp-route-bConfirm="@true" asp-action="ItemIndex" class="genric-btn green circle"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Finalize</button>
            <a asp-controller="CreditNotes" asp-action="CreateEdit" asp-route-id="@Model.CreditNoteId" class="genric-btn danger circle "><i class="fa fa-times "></i> Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ItemIndex(bool bConfirm, bool bSendEmail)
{
    .... My codes are here
}
```

I couldn't get proper value from the parameter named "bSendEmail". Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.CheckBox("bSendEmail", false)
```

Because:

the `<input type="checkbox" id="chkSendMail" name="bSendEmail" class="my-checkbox">`

Html Result:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSendMail" name="bSendEmail" class="my-checkbox">
```

there is no value property.

the `@Html.CheckBox("bSendEmail", false)`

Html Result:

```
<input id="bSendEmail" name="bSendEmail" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

result:

[image]